# how to translate "0x%llx" from C to python

Tags: python, string-formatting

I'm reading some strings from a memory buffer, written by a `C` program. I need to fetch them using python and print them. however when I encounter a string containing `%llx`  python does not know how to parse this:

```
"unsupported format character 'l' (0x6c) at index 14"
```

I could use `replace('%llx','%x')` but than it would not be a long long.. would python handle this correctly in this case?

Comment: Just try it and see what happens

Comment: @norlesh -  I have tried it, but I cannot anticipate every option that will come up. I am asking for a more correct way to do this.

Comment: are you using  PyString_FromFormat() ?

Comment: "I need to fetch them using python and print them" - do you actually need to convert to and from an integer type, or can you just read it as a string and print the string directly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tested on both Python v3.3.3 and v2.7.6 :

```
>>> print('%x' % 523433939134152323423597861958781271347434)
6023bedba8c47434c84785469b1724910ea
```

Answer (score 2):

```
 than it would not be a long long
```

Python (essentially) doesn't have any concept of a long long. If you're pulling `long long`s from C code, just use `%x` and be done with it -- you're not ever going to get values from the C code that are out of the `long long` range, the only issue that could arise is if you were trying to send them from Python code into C. Just use (with a new-style format string):

```
print('{0:x}'.format(your_int))
```